# Make an entire <div> linkable when a module is loaded inside to it

Tags: css, html, joomla2.5, loadmodule

My question relates to make an entire DIV linkable when a module is loaded inside to it (Joomla 2.5.latest).

I have 4 boxes side by side, all  as below in my custom-css.

```
.box1 {
  width: 22%;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 5%;
 -moz-border-radius: 5%;
```

etc. etc. etc.

---

In my HTML I have this:

```
<div class="box1">{module Colours module: Challenges}</div>
```

I use Joomla 2.5. latest and I loaded a module inside a module, i.e. the colours module challenges goes into box1 and box1 is inside a Joomla module (together with 3 other modules).

---

Every box (1,2,3,4) has a different module loaded inside it.

---

What I would love to have is the ENTIRE  box 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 LINKABLE with above plan??? I read about:

```
<a class="box1" href="http://www.abc.com">{loadmodule}</a>
```

but this does not work at all, not sure why. If I leave out the {loadmodule} part, then it works, but that doesn´t help me. I need the module loaded inside.

I would like to accomplish my wish in CSS/HTML itself (javascript is too far over my head for now). Any help much appreciated. Thanks, guys.

P.S. I am a complete newbie but trying to learn CSS/HTML fast... :))

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if I get you right, but I think that adding `display: block` to your `.box1` should make your `<a>` solution work...  (`<a>` is default inline type).

If your problem is with Joomla, then sorry but I don't know Joomla

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick reply. But that didnt work. I have a CSS/HTML issue and basically I want content to load inside a DIV (this part I figured out and that is working perfectly), but now I want that whole DIV+content to be fully linkable, so how to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean "linkable"? That if you click on it, it will redirect you to another page? Well but I guess that it's Joomla issue and I don't know Joomla, so I'm afraid that I won't be able to help you...